# How to get the previous value of a variable

Tags: java, android, integer

I made a program that thinks of a number and you have to guess the number.
It is working well, but I got stuck.
First of all, you (the player) has 10 tries in a round. Every wrong guess subtracts 1 from the tries. If you reach 0 you lose.
The variable where the thing stores the randomized number looks like this:

```
int guess = Integer.parseInt(etGuess.getText().toString());
```

Of course I have an edittext field with the name etGuess.

So when the player enters the same number twice (for example: 5, then 5 again), the program subtracts 1 then again 1 (so 2) tries.
I'd like to know how can I get the previous value of the guess integer and check whether it was already guessed or not.

I think of something like this:

```
if ( previous_guess != guess )
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Two very different languages.

Comment: your best bet would be to initialize an array and store all the user guesses in it. Create a loop with couple of conditions (1. when the number entered matches a previous entered number and 2. if the entered number does not match the random number) that will cycle through the whole array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Here's how I would do this:

```
//Declare the variable outside of a function
HashSet<Integer> previousGuesses = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

```
//Check if it is already guessed
if (set.contains(guess)) {
     //Alert the user that they can't use this.
}
```

```
//Adding a variable to it in a function: 
set.add(guess);
```

Make sure to test if it contains before adding it or preforming any of the regular code.

Comment: Shouldn't the check be done before adding the guess?

Comment: @Tyler Yea.  I've edited the post to fit with that order now; there isn't any code provided to make the order clear unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Store all of your previous numbers in an array and then check the array then the player enters a new number.

Comment: A java.util.Set probably would be more appropriate.